# Selecting cells that have been Formated with Conditional Formatting

Tags: macos, excel, excel-2011

I'm looking for a way to copy a series of cells that have been Conditional Formatted. We have a spreadsheet with cells that we have tagged as "TBD". I created a rule to formate every Row that has "TBD" anywhere in it, which is what we want. Now I'm looking for a way to copy or select everything that we have formatted and have a way to copy it to another document etc.

This is a screenshot of the rule I created:

[image]
[image]

Thanks

Excel 2011, OSX 10.8.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the AutoFilter with criteria ****TBD**** and copy the filtered cells.

Comment: Solved it using the same approach... Selected a cell that was coloured and had "TBD" then used the Auto Filter with filter by Color.